# Avoid append in Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I'm trying to fetch content of a http body in the following way

```java
public Flux<DataBuffer> getFileContent(URI uri) {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri(uri)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
            .doFirst(() -> log.info("Start download of file with uri {}", uri))
            .doOnError(error -> log.error("Found an error for file with uri {} - {}", uri, error.getLocalizedMessage()))
            .retryBackoff(numRetries, Duration.ofSeconds(backOff), Duration.ofSeconds(backOff));
    }
```

This is working. I pass this `Flux<DataBuffer>` to another method that does the following

```java
public Mono<Void> apply(Path path, Flux<DataBuffer> fileContent) {
        return DataBufferUtils
            .write(fileContent, path)
            .doOnError(error -> {
                log.error("Could not save to disk the file {}", path);
                try {
                    Files.deleteIfExists(path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.debug("Could not delete the file {}", path);
                }
            })
            .doOnSuccess(unused -> log.info("Finished saving file {}", path.toString()));
    }
```

What it seems to me is that in case of a network error during the initial Flux `retrieve`, the `retryBackoff` tries to recover from that error and tries to download the file again.
That will cause the `DataBufferUrils.write` to write two times the initial content of the file.

How can I make the `write` to "restart" in case of errors and truncate the half-downloaded file?

Comment: cant you just add a check that if the file exists delete it, then write to it... if it fails, the next time it gets called it will check for the existance of the file, delete it and then crate and write.

Comment: @Toerktumlare the problem is that `DatabufferUtils` doesn't know that something failed because of the `retryBackoff` policy. It seems like there were no error and that the Flux<DataBuffer> is a stream without interruption

Comment: Does it have to know? If retry starts the download over, then you just delete the file on every call to DataBufferUtils

Comment: You could move retry logic  `retryBackoff(numRetries, Duration.ofSeconds(backOff), Duration.ofSeconds(backOff))` down to your pipeline to restart the whole download logic and not just `getFileContent`